# what is the best way in asp.net-mvc / SQL server, to store expensive calculated data and serve it up fast like stackoverflow

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance, metrics

i have a similar requirement to stackoverflow to show a number of metrics on a page in my asp.net-mvc site that are very expensive to calculate.   Stackoverflow has a lot of metrics on the page (like user accept rate, etc) which clearly is not being calculated on the fly on page request, given that it would be too slow.

What is a recommended practice for serving up calculated data really fast without the performance penalty (assuming we can accept that this data maybe a little out of date.

is this stored in some caching layer or stored in some other "results" database table so every day there is a job to calculate this data and store the results so they can be queries directly?

assuming that i am happy to deal with the delayed of having this data as a snapshot,what is the best solution for this type of problem.

Comment: (I'm trying to think of a good way to answer this that isn't "every way you need"...)

Comment: Further to my point below, you asked "What is a recommended practice for serving up calculated data really fast without the performance penalty (assuming we can accept that this data maybe a little out of date". This is a textbook example of where caching is valuable. Without further information about the size & volume of your data and how frequently it changes and how "out of date" you can tolerate, it'll be difficult to make specific recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably they may be relying on the Redis data store for such calculations and caching. This [post](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2011/04/async-redis-await-booksleeve.html) from marcgravell may help.

Answer (score 1):

yes, the answer is caching, how you do it is (can be) the complicated part, if you are using NHibernate adding caching is really easy, is part of your configuration and on the queries you just add .Cacheable and it manages it for you. Caching also depends on the type of environment, if you're using a single worker, web farm or web garden, you would have to build a caching layer to accomodate for your scenario

Comment: i don't think you are answering the question . . it doesn't clarify when these types of calculation would be made.  By saying caching gives me the assumption that the first time someone requests it, it will be calculated and then the follow up requests will hit the cache . . i am looking for both sides here . .

Comment: @OOO - I don't understand your response to BlackTigerX here. If you want data that is expensive to calculate you want to calculate it infrequently and store it in a manner and location that's useful to your site's rendering engine. That's caching. You may choose to use caching provided as part of your data access or ORM layer. You may choose to cache data in text/XML/binary/whatever files on your web server. You may choose to implement an in memory database of these cached values. Whichever way you look at it, your using cached data.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a somewhat-recent technique, one really great way to structure your system to make stuff like this possible is by using [Command and Query Responsibility Segregation](http://wrightthisblog.blogspot.com/2010/01/cqrs-overview-chicago-altnet-user-group.html), more often referred to by CQRS.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to my blog post!  People may also want to look [here](http://elegantcode.com/2009/11/11/cqrs-la-greg-young/) and [here](http://www.blogcoward.com/category/15.aspx) for additional resources.